# What on Earth is this kanji character?

Tags: kanji, writing-identification

[image]

I was watching a Japanese YouTube video and the ending screen that says the usual ご視聴ありがとうございます followed by talking about what the next video was going to be, etc... I understand the context of this sentence, except for that darn verb with the scribble character. My guess is that it's some kind of ichidan verb, based on the よう part. For the life of me I cannot identify the kanji used here though. Help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## [纏](http://tangorin.com/kanji/%E7%BA%8F)

And the caption says:

> 一回に纏めようと思ったんですが無理でした。

...and likely to be typeset in [AR POP4B](http://designpocket.jp/dl_font_category/detail.aspx?bid=3108).

[image]

Comment: どうもありがとうございました！I was really scratching my head there, aha.

Answer (score 9):

The kanji and Hiragana part you are asking - 纏め is pronounced "matome," and means to "put together." 纏め is a noun, and its verb form is 纏める.The whole sentence - 一回に纏めようと思ったんですが、無理でした means "I wished to put them (everything) together at once, but I couldn't. 纏 is also known as a decorated pole sign of firefighters' identifying their team name in Edo era. I don't think the character, 纏 is included in 当用漢字 the list of regular use kanji, and many are difficult for today's young people to read. So it's no wonder for non-native Japanese have difficulty in reading.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation! Yeah, I'm usually pretty good at figuring out even unknown kanji, but this one had me stumped. I'm glad I will know it for the future from now on. Hah.